# Mapping const char** to Java type with JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

I am trying to use a C++ library in Java with JNA. In the header file of the library I have the following method declaration:

```
extern "C" void foo(const char** bar);
```

The paramterer `bar` should be passed to `foo` empty, and `foo` vill assign it a value that I want to retreive in Java. How should the corresponding Java method declaration be set up (e.g. what Java type should I map `bar` to), and how can I use it?

I have tried the following Java declarations:

```
void foo(String bar);
void foo(String[] bar);
void foo(Pointer bar);
```

They all result in the following error when I call `foo`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

Comment: Following the Javadoc [marshalling](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html#marshalling) `String[]`. If you get the sources [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna.git) you have the up-to-date documentation in `./www`.

Comment: The linked documentation suggests `String[]` for `char**`. Does this being `const char**` make any difference? Using `String[]` gives me the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SubOptimal After testing some more, turns out using `String[]` works - I just failed to get it to work due to an unrelated error. If you want to write an answer based on your comments, feel free to do so. Otherwise I will write a self answer. Thank you.

Comment: I add an answer with a short example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find below a small snippet.

**libfoo.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" void foo(const char** bar);

void foo(const char** bar) {
    for (int i = 0; bar[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", bar[i]);
    }
}
```

**LibFooDemo.java**

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class LibFooDemo {

    public interface FooLibrary extends Library {
        FooLibrary INSTANCE = (FooLibrary)
                Native.loadLibrary("foo", FooLibrary.class);
        void foo(String[] format);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] vals = {"foo", "bar", "foobar"};
        FooLibrary.INSTANCE.foo(vals);
    }
}
```

compile all sources

```
gcc -c -fPIC libfoo.cpp -o libfoo.o
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so  libfoo.o
javac -cp jna-4.2.1.jar LibFooDemo.java
```

run the Java program

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -cp jna-4.2.1.jar:. LibFooDemo
```

output

```
foo
bar
foobar
```