# How to map function returning array of strings (const char**) to Java with JNA?

Tags: java, c++, jna

I am trying to use a C++ library in Java with JNA. In the header file of the library I have the following method declaration:

```
extern "C" const char** foo(void* bar);
```

The length of the returned array is known, and so is the possible maximum length of the individual elements in it. How can I map and use this function in Java? I have tried the following Java declarations:

```
String[] foo(Pointer bar);
Pointer foo(Pointer bar);
StringArray foo(Pointer bar);
```

They all result in the following error when I call `foo`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

(This question is related to, but not identical to, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404556/mapping-const-char-to-java-type-with-jna).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pointer foo(Pointer bar)` is the one you want, and then use `Pointer` methods to extract the data you want.

```
Memory data = new Memory(256);
Pointer p = foo(data);
Pointer[] parray = p.getPointerArray(0);
for (Pointer p : parray) {
    System.out.println(p.getString(0));
}
```

The invalid memory access is likely due to you passing in some data that is not formatted the way the callee expects.